# WPF TabItem Tittle controlled by Frame inside

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TabConrol` that when a user does certain things, a new `TabItem` is programmatically added. In this tab there is a `Frame` that will contain the desired `Page.XAML`. This is all working perfectly like this;

```
private void addNewTab()
{
    TabItem tab = new TabItem();
    Grid g = new Grid();
    Frame f = newFrame();
    g.Children.Add(f);
    tab.Content = g;
    tab.Title = "Hard Coded Title"
    MyTabControl.Items.Add(tab);
    MyTabControl.SelectedItem = tab;
}

private Frame newFrame()
{
   Frame f = new Frame();
   //Full logic for Frame removed
   f.Navigate(new MyPage());
   return f;
}
```

As you can see the title of the `TabItem` is hard coded.  What I am wanting is that the `Page.XAML` could control the `TabItem` title.  I figured something like this might work;

```
Binding bind = new Binding("Title");
bind.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
bind.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true;
bind.NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true;
bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
tab.DataContext = f;
tab.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bind);
```

This doesn't work at all.  Am I going about this completely wrong?  Is my bind incorrect.  Any help would be great!

Comment: delete all that and use proper XAML.

Comment: @HighCore Please tell me how to generate new TabItems in XAML based on the selected item of an AutoComplete box.  Also depending on the result of the AutoComplete box certain logic must be run in the MainWindow and some logic has to be past to the Frame.

Comment: the UI is not the right place to put any of your logic. Create a proper ViewModel with an ObservableCollection and use DataBinding to populate the TabControl from the OC. Also bind the AutoCompleteBox to a string in the VM and do your logic in the VM when the text changes.

Comment: Also, please use proper naming conventions. Your methods should be ProperCased, i.e, `AddNewTab()` instead of `addNewTab()`, which btw shouldn't even exist to begin with because you don't "add new tabs" in WPF, but instead use DataBinding as mentioned above.